# Pandas deleting my zero index when groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a very basic groupby on a column to have counts for n different columns of the dataframe :

```
counts = (dataframe.groupby(['label'])[best_features_names_ordered[i]].sum() for i in indices)
```

Here is the column 'label' of the dataframe :
[image]
The other columns are words.

My `best_features_names_ordered` variable is a basic list containing words
:

[image]
The groupby works well, excepted when one of the values of the column 'labels' is equal to 0!

Here an example, the labels are equal to `{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}` but the 0 has disappeared:

[image]

However, the labels have the 0 ...:

[image]

Does pandas delete my 0 index when grouping ? Why ? How can I solve this ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you add some sample data, 5-6 rows?

Comment: I added to more images. I am sorry they are not very convenient to understand but I'm obliged to work in command line and the calls hierarchy to have this is quite complex.

Comment: `dataframe.groupby(['label'][best_features_names_ordered[i]].sum() for i in indices, as_index=False)` ?? Without sample data, hard to test it!

Comment: I have already tested with `as_index`, it takes freaking long to execute.

Comment: If for example the labels are ['negative', 'neutral', 'positive'], I have no problem. I think it is due to the 0 class that becomes an index when doing the groupby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed that the 0 is removed by pandas when indexing the result of *groupby*.

I soluced the problem by using string classes (therefore string indexes) which prevent pandas from deleting tha value '0'.

However, if anybody has a better solution, please don't hesitate.